# Why can't I access Home Assistant via IPv6 from outside?

Tags: ipv6, raspbian, fritzbox

I would like to be able to access my Raspberry Pi from outside of my local network. The raspberry pi runs `Raspbian GNU/Linux 10` and Home Assistant. For example when I want to check if I really closed the door I could look this up via home assistant - if I could access it.

I have an AVM **Fritz!Box 7530** and I am a Telekom customer living in Germany.

When I go to **Home Network -> Network** I see that the Raspberry Pi is marked as **Exposed host**. When I click on it, I see "Port Assigned Externally IPv6" has 8123 as value (the port of home assistant). When I click on the pencil (edit) button, I see 4 IPv6 addresses. Two start with `fe80::`, one starts with `fd00::`, and two start with `2003:ed:`.

When I'm in my network, I can access the device via `http://[2003:ed: ...]:8123`. When I'm outside of the network, I can't. When I try to ping it via http://www.ipv6now.com.au/pingme.php I have 100% package loss. I tried both the `2003:ed:` addresses.

How can I access the raspberry pi / home assistant from outside of my network?

### Fritz-Box Settings

I've selected the Raspberry Pi in the Fritz Box settings:

[image]

scrolling down a bit

[image]

When I ping that `2003:ed:…4e` address with http://www.ipv6now.com.au/pingme.php I get

> Destination unreachable: Address unreachable

### More information

```
$ ifconfig
[...]
wlan0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet [pi local IPv4]  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.178.255
        inet6 [2003:ed: ... public IPv6; ends with 70]  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 [fe80::... IPv6]  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 74:da:38:33:78:8a  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 25285  bytes 6101412 (5.8 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 6718  bytes 2315017 (2.2 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

$ curl icanhazip.com
[2003:ed: ... public IPv6; ends with 70]
```

So that is my public IP.

Let's make sure the server is listening publicly:

```
$ netstat -lnp
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8123            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      - 
...
tcp6       0      0 :::8123                 :::*                    LISTEN      -   
...
```

That is fine, isn't it?

Now let's check the Raspberry OS firewall settings:

```
$ sudo ip6tables -S
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

The IPv6 which I get from `icanhazip.com` ending with 70 is not one of the two IPv6 which I see in the FritzBox! What does that mean?

### IPv6 Settings

[image]

Comment: "Did try to open the ports and direct all traffic on 8123 to 2003:ed: ...?" => I think so. How can I verify that?

Comment: "Unless 2003:ed: ... is your public IPv6 address" - I think that is a part of the issue. The fritzbox did not show the public IPv6. I now have the public IPv6 - it starts with `2003:ed:` end ends with `70`. I can use that internally to access the Raspberry Pi, but not from the outside 

Comment: The Pi already has a public IPv6 address, just like it's supposed to be. It does not require port forwarding. It still requires a firewall rule though.

Comment: @DanielB Where do I need to do this? In the Fritz box? I couldn't find anything - the devie is marked as "Unrestricted [Access]". I've also pasted the relevant output of `netstat -lnp` from the raspberry pi.

Comment: your `netstat` sample doesn't show `tcp6` connection ((it should have `:::8123`), did you edited it out ?

Comment: @Archemar Oops, sorry, I didn't know that was relevant. I've added it (it shows way more, but the rest seems not to be relevant)

Answer (score 1):

Since you can connect from the local network using the Pi’s public IPv6 address, we can assume that everything on the device itself is set up correctly.

With IPv6, the consumer router no longer does NAT (or at least that’s how it’s supposed to work). This means every device on the local network has its own internet-routable IPv6 address. This is the *2003:ed:…:70* address of your Pi. Because there is no NAT, port forwarding is not required. However, to protect devices on the local network, most IPv6-capable routers still have a firewall. It is set to disallow unsolicited inbound traffic by default, including ping requests.

To set up the IPv6 firewall on an AVM FRITZ!Box, you need to go to *Internet* → *Permit Access* → *Port Sharing* (*Freigaben* → *Portfreigaben* in German). From there, add a new device (or because you already have the Pi there, edit it) and select the desired options. You probably want:

- Enable PING6 (to easily check connectivity)
- A port rule in the lower table for port 8123, at least for IPv6

If you set it up correctly, the table will contain a dedicated row for the IPv6 rule, like this:

[image: firewall rule table]

Once you confirm all the changes, you should be able to connect to the Pi’s IPv6 address on port 8123 from the internet.

Comment: I've added a screenshot of the current settings (which don't work). Should I change anything?

Comment: There is also this `IPv6 interface ID` setting. Do I need to adjust this?

Comment: You generally do _not_ want to adjust this. However, it appears to be incorrect. I suggest you remove the device settings entirely and add them again. The interface ID would then be automatically correctly filled in. It is the local part of the IPv6 address. If you have IPv6 privacy enabled on your Pi, you’ll have to disable it. // Also, please don’t use the “Exposed Host“ feature unless you absolutely have to.

Comment: I did that, but it still doesn't work. Nothing has changed. Is maybe "DHCPv6 Rapid commit" an issue? (I've added a screenshot of those IPv6 settings to the question)

Comment: This is entirely unrelated. All I can tell you is the obvious: The IPv6 address in the firewall rule and on the actual device do not match, so the rule does not match.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean from outside that you are connected via the vpn server in the fritzbox, then the issue is that the vpn connection is only ipv4.... so you won't be able to connect via the ipv6 adresses...